# Getting the checklists from Notes.app via Applescript (Js)

Tags: macos, applescript

I would like to find checklists from my notes. With AppleScript (Js) I can get the body of a note as HTML or plain text. However, I cannot identify the checklist items.

---

[image: A sample note as displayed by the Notes app]

The `body` returns HTML content:

```
<div><h1>Sample note</h1></div>\n
<div><h1>This a title</h1></div>\n
<div><h2>This is a heading</h2></div>\n
<div><h3>This is a subheading</h3></div>\n
<div><h3><br></h3></div>\n
<div>This is a paragraph with the “body” format.</div>\n
<div><br></div>\n<div>And another “body” paragraph.</div>\n
<div><br></div>\n
<div><tt>Some monospaced text. On 3 lines (this is line 0)</tt></div>\n
<div><tt>And line 2</tt></div>\n
<div><tt>Finally, line 3</tt></div>\n
<div><tt><br></tt></div>\n
<ul>\n
<li>Bullet 1</li>\n
<li>Bullet 2</li>\n
</ul>\n
<div><br></div>\n
<ul class=\"Apple-dash-list\">\n
<li>Dash 1</li>\n
<li>Dash 2</li>\n
</ul>\n
<div><br></div>\n
<ol>\n
<li>Number 1</li>\n
<li>Number 2</li>\n
</ol>\n
<div><br></div>\n
<ul>\n
<li>Checklist item 1</li>\n
<li>Checklist item 2</li>\n
</ul>\n
<div><br></div>\n
<div><object><table cellspacing=\"0\" cellpadding=\"0\" style=\"border-collapse: collapse; direction: ltr\">\n
<tbody>\n
<tr><td valign=\"top\" style=\"border-style: solid; border-width: 1.0px 1.0px 1.0px 1.0px; border-color: #ccc; padding: 3.0px 5.0px 3.0px 5.0px; min-width: 70px\"><div>Table, row 1, col 1</div>\n
</td><td valign=\"top\" style=\"border-style: solid; border-width: 1.0px 1.0px 1.0px 1.0px; border-color: #ccc; padding: 3.0px 5.0px 3.0px 5.0px; min-width: 70px\"><div>Table, row 1, col 2</div>\n
</td></tr>\n
<tr><td valign=\"top\" style=\"border-style: solid; border-width: 1.0px 1.0px 1.0px 1.0px; border-color: #ccc; padding: 3.0px 5.0px 3.0px 5.0px; min-width: 70px\"><div>Table, row 2, col 1</div>\n
</td><td valign=\"top\" style=\"border-style: solid; border-width: 1.0px 1.0px 1.0px 1.0px; border-color: #ccc; padding: 3.0px 5.0px 3.0px 5.0px; min-width: 70px\"><div>Table, row 2, col 2</div>\n
</td></tr>\n
</tbody>\n
</table></object><br></div>\n
<div><tt><br></tt></div>\n
```

And `plaintext` give, .. plain text:

```
"Sample note\nThis a title\nThis is a heading\nThis is a subheading\n\nThis is a paragraph with the “body” format.\n\nAnd another “body” paragraph.\n\nSome monospaced text. On 3 lines (this is line 0)\nAnd line 2\nFinally, line 3\n\nBullet 1\nBullet 2\n\nDash 1\nDash 2\n\nNumber 1\nNumber 2\n\nChecklist item 1\nChecklist item 2\n\n￼\n\n"
```

---

**EDIT:**

I think this is not doable. Because the "Open in Pages" menu does not show the checklist in Pages.

---

Is there any way to identify a checklist or checklist-item ?

I would prefer with JavaScript syntax. But I can use AppleScript if this is the only way.

Thanks,